# Paper gets out HL-2250DN to slow

Tags: 12.04, printing, brother

I've got a printer 'Brother HL-2250DN'.
My problem: it sometimes prints extremely slow...!
My Ubuntu: Precise Pangolin

Comment: define "prints extremely slow"

Comment: thank you for the response, Lord of Time. It was about, I don't know, 5 or 10 minutes for 2 pages. But for the moment, my problem seems to be solved (see also the comment I gave just a few seconds ago, below)

Answer (score 0):

In the printer dialog you can select under Print -> Order -> Priority. There you can select the priority between low, middle, high and urgent.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. In the meantime, I've found another thing that seemed to help, too. (hope the solution will keep to seem working). In fact, it was a series of things, I don't know which one did the trick. It works like this. When in Window 'Printing', I chose 'Properties'. Then to 'apparatus'. (hoping I translate well, my Ubuntu is in Dutch :-). Then I chose Print Quelity: Draft; Color Mode: Monochrome; Resolution: 300x300 dpi. And, (... see next part of answer in next box)

Comment: (..) and then, interestingly, I saw that the Type language Printer was PDF, although I printed 'docx'. So I changed that to PostScript.Then printing got a lot faster. Exactly the same document, a little earlier, took me very long to print- 5 or 10 minutes for 2 pages, I think. After my changes: maybe one minute.

Comment: Yes, the printing method could also be the cause of the long printing duration.
Could you also mark the question as completed?

Comment: "mark the question as completed?": how do I do that?

Comment: left of my answer, there is a 'star' button. When this question is displayed in a list  (like on the homescreen) you see that a resolution was found.